# ViewPager in Fragment frequently displays black screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` within a `Fragment`. Within the `ViewPager` are fragments. The fragments in the `ViewPager` are displayed at black screens. I've tried:

- Switching the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
- implementing the `getItemId` method

and various other things I've found online. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my adapter:

```
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return ratedFrag;
                case 1:
                    return unratedFrag;
                case 2:
                    return collectionFrag;
                default:
                    return ratedFrag;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Rated";
                case 1:
                    return "To Rate";
                case 2:
                    return "Collections";
                default:
                    return "Rated";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 100 + position;
        }

    };
```

**Edit:** fragment that implement pager:

```
public class JournalActivity extends MasterFragment {

    private final static String TAG = "JournalActivity";

    @InjectView(R.id.pager)
    private ViewPager pager;

    private EntryFragment ratedFrag;
    private EntryFragment unratedFrag;
    private CollectionFragment collectionFrag;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_journal, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void setupViews() {

        ratedFrag = new EntryFragment(); 
        unratedFrag = new EntryFragment(); 
        collectionFrag = new CollectionFragment();

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return ratedFrag;
                    case 1:
                        return unratedFrag;
                    case 2:
                        return collectionFrag;
                    default:
                        return ratedFrag;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return "Rated";
                    case 1:
                        return "To Rate";
                    case 2:
                        return "Collections";
                    default:
                        return "Rated";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 100 + position;
            }

        };


        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        tabs.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        tabs.setIndicatorHeight(5);
        tabs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tabs.setTextSize((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_medium));
        tabs.setTypeface(Fonts.getInstance().secondaryFontBold, Typeface.BOLD);

    }
}
```

Below is the `EntryFragment` class:

```
public class EntryFragment extends MasterFragment {

    private final static String TAG = "EntryFragment";

    private String color;
    private List<Entry> entries;
    private WineListAdapter listAdapter;

    @InjectView(R.id.search_container)
    private LinearLayout searchContainer;

    @InjectView(R.id.search_view)
    private SearchView searchView;

    @InjectView(R.id.filter_button)
    private SecondaryButton filterButton;

    @InjectView(R.id.list)
    private ListView listView;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static EntryFragment newInstance() {
        EntryFragment fragment = new EntryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public EntryFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.entries = (List<Entry>)getArguments().get("entries");
        }
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // getActivity() can be null if called before onAttach
        listAdapter = new WineListAdapter(getActivity(),
                entries != null ? entries : new ArrayList<Entry>(),
                SortType.RATING);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mListener.entryWasSelected((Entry) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: post the whole class that implement that above code

Comment: just try using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() when you initializing adapter.

Comment: Thanks @manish, this was _exactly_ my problem/solution.  Now I need to go fully understand why.